# How to quickly test a page locally

Tags: r, opencpu

While writing/debugging an app I need to quickly test pages. Just using

```
install()
opencpu$browser("mypage.html")
```

is not enough as the page doesn't seem to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to restart the server after installing, or the page might not be updated.

I wrote the following function I've been happily working with for the last few months:

```
testApp <- function(page="",port="",pkg=gsub("^.*\\/","",getwd())){
    require("opencpu")
    require("devtools")
    document();
    # install the package
    install();
    # restart the server (or it will display cached things)
    opencpu$stop();
    if(port==""){
        opencpu$start();
    }else{
        opencpu$start(port);
    }
    # visualize
    opencpu$browse(paste0("/library/",pkg,"/www/",page));
}
```

You can then just do:

```
testApp()
```

to test `index.html` or

```
testApp("mypage.html")
```

to test a specific page.